# FTP connection issues

Tags: python, ftp

I have been tasked to try and build an interface to download and Upload files to an external FTP site which we use to communicate with a stock exchange.

For this we are communicating through the Filezilla FTP package.

I have spent the last few days researching and reading various pieces but cannot get the connection to work.

Now if I do a basic connection (as below) to the Filezilla website I get a connection.

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('filezilla-project.org')
Welcome = ftp.getwelcome()
print(Welcome)

# 220 FZ router and firewall tester ready
```

Basic I am trying to use the following (example not real credentials)

```
Protocol: FTP - File Transfer Protocol
Host: 212.31.105.26
Port: 
Encryption: Require implicit FTP over TLS
Logon Type: Normal
User: L12
Password: GetConnected
```

I have created the below using various snippets etc. I do not get a fail message or timeout but I also do not get a response.

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS
def connectftp():
    ftp=ftplib.FTP('212.31.105.26', timeout=0.001)
    print(ftp.getwelcome())
    #ftp.login(username, password)
    ftp.login(user='L12', passwd ='GetConnected')
    #login_response = ftp.login(username, password)
    login_response = ftp.login(user='L12', passwd ='GetConnected')
    print(login_response)
```

Comment: Not sure where the error is, but ensure that you don't have a .netrc in your home directory as that totally screws things up.  [just saying.. not saying it's totally relevant to your problem.]

Comment: ewong - are you refering to the home directory on the FTP site? if so I have checked and there is no .netrc directory

Comment: no, your home directory on your system doing the ftp site interaction.

Comment: So what happens when you execute the code? Why do you set `timeout=0.001`? + I do not think that `.netrc` is relevant here.

Comment: Martin Prikryl - I have taken out the "timeout" - ```= RESTART: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\FTPConnection.py
>>> ``` is what is displayed when I execute the code (that is the same as with the timout)